# Is LIKE 'xxx%' equivalent to range query? How do LIKE 'xxx%' use index?

Tags: mysql

Some one says, (1)LIKE 'xxx%' is equivalent to range query; (2)columns after the range column cannot use the index. But, I find the two statement are contradictory in an example which will be provided below. So, I want to know what the exact process of querying index tree when we use LIKE 'xxx%'.

I used the [employees.titles table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/) of MySQL document.

Here is the table structure.

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title     | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| from_date | date        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| to_date   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here is the index structure.

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| titles |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | emp_no      | A         |      300698 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| titles |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | title       | A         |      441654 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| titles |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | from_date   | A         |      441654 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Here is the query statement.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employees.titles 
               WHERE emp_no='10001' 
                     AND title LIKE 'Senior%' 
                     AND from_date='1986-06-26';
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | titles | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 59      | NULL |    1 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

If title "LIKE 'Senior%'" is equivalent to "title >=Senior and title < Senios", why the key_len is 59, which means all columns of the primary key are used?

The result of EXPLAIN format=JSON

```
mysql> EXPLAIN format=json SELECT * FROM employees.titles WHERE emp_no='10001' AND title LIKE 'Senior%' AND from_date='1986-06-26'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
EXPLAIN: {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "1.29"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "titles",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY"
      ],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "emp_no",
        "title"
      ],
      "key_length": "59",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 0,
      "filtered": "10.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.00",
        "eval_cost": "0.01",
        "prefix_cost": "1.29",
        "data_read_per_join": "3"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "emp_no",
        "title",
        "from_date",
        "to_date"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`employees`.`titles`.`from_date` = '1986-06-26') and (`employees`.`titles`.`emp_no` = '10001') and (`employees`.`titles`.`title` like 'Senior%'))"
    }
  }
}
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Short answer no... as the optimizer can also choose to scan the complete table with `title LIKE 'Senior%'` if a large part in the table off title column contains a string that starts with `Senior`

Comment: this question is to broad to answer as the optimizer is a heavy beast to understand or explain..

Comment: @RaymondNijland please check the result of `EXPLAIN format=JSON` added into the question. `used_key_parts` clearly indicate that only first two columns are used. `key_len` is probably accounting for multi-byte characters as well, OR, it does not do accurate estimate when handling `LIKE ..%`. Although the first case is more likely.

Comment: This was a tricky case as those two column and that key_len matched more or less the complete primary key length... Not sure whats going on here @MadhurBhaiya  as `return explain_key_and_len_quick(tab->quick_optim());` in [Explain_join::explain_key_and_len()](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/opt_explain.cc#L1438) then might give approximated values which happens in range scans..  **Jet a other thing in the standard (table) EXPLAIN output to  take with a grain of salt it seams or atleast handle with some care**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering of column in an index is very important for a particular `WHERE` clause. In your current Primary Key, the order is `emp_no` -> `title` -> `from_date`. When using `AND` condition between various columns, MySQL will continue using the columns in the Composite index equating to a **constant** value,  until it encounters the Range condition.

Now, note that `LIKE 'Senior%` is basically a Range condition, because there are various possibilities in `title` with `Senior` as prefix. Because, MySQL encountered the Range condition at the second column in the index, it does not use the third column in index, *i.e.*, `from_date` (`from_date='1986-06-26').

You can confirm this from the `Extra` column in your `EXPLAIN` result. It says [`Using Where`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html) there. It basically means that after doing the Index Lookup (using the first two columns), it goes into Data Tree, and gets the `from_date` value to filter out based on your `WHERE` condition (`from_date='1986-06-26').

If you want all the columns in the index to be used, you will need to change the ordering of columns in your Primary Key to the following, or define a new index:

`(emp_no, from_date, title)`

Depending on your MySQL version, you can get much more details, if you run `EXPLAIN format=JSON`. Especially, look at the `used columns` part in the JSON result from the Explain. Another way to check is if you define the new indexes (as specified above), and re-run the query, you will notice that `Using Where` has gone away from the `Explain` result now.

**Edit**

Thanks for adding the `EXPLAIN format=JSON` result. You can clearly see `used_key_parts` value in it:

```
"used_key_parts": [
        "emp_no",
        "title"
      ]
```

It clearly indicates that only first two columns in the Primary Key are used.

Comment: @RaymondNijland if you ask me, keylen is not really a trustworthy parameter. That is why a more reliable hint is `USING WHERE` in the Extra column. I have found many times that keylen does not give accurate values

Comment: *"I have found many times that keylen does not give accurate values "* i never encounterd that or atleast never noticed it, i think i am going to track down how MySQL gets this number ... agree the question is incomplete as it is removing the "chatty" comments..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think we are missing the multibyte calculation for computing key_length in varchar (utf8). Maybe there are multibyte characters. MySQL document though seems to indicate that key_len is the length of the keys used in multi-part keys.

Comment: yes i know that statement in the manual always believed because of that statement that key_len would be accurate in the explain, you bring some doubt where you said it wasn't..  Annyhow i found in the past more wierd things in the EXPLAIN output where it didn't say "using temporary" when using [UNION](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54178/how-to-get-rid-of-using-temporary-when-using-distinct-in-mysql/54184#54184)..

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I found it is as you said. I also has the doubt about key_length.